# @include blade store in database

Tags: php, laravel

I have some code in database

```
<div class="container py-1">
  @include('layouts.tester')
</div>
```

When I show data from database i show
"@include('layouts.tester')"

I want to include my file than show text.
how can I do it to make it work?

Comment: I don't want to be unpleasant, but you should read documentation first. Check out [views](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/views)

Comment: Documentation doesn't help me. I know that exist documentation.

Comment: would you please share more like folder structure or some other relevant codes.

Comment: Code is there http://ntpd.eu/rd0ka

Comment: Are you storing `<div class="container py-1"> @include('layouts.tester') </div>` into your database and retriveing this tow view? :(

Comment: Yes, I store this in database

Comment: Why would you even do this?

Comment: Because I have WSYIGW editor in my page and I want to change content in page by text editor

Answer (score 0):

@include means include files include a blade file. So for this you va to @extends('layouts.app') then where you want to show the file just use yield like below

```
@yield('content')
```

Then in which page you want to replace just use it like this

```
@section('content')
//your buttons/forms goes here
@endsection
```

Comment: In my page i see a text "@yield('terminy_szkolen')". I want to see block html

Comment: Yes you can repkace that terminy_szkolen with content or any other keyword you like then simply call a section method like i said in my answer

Comment: What you are actually trying to do?!!! Ca you give some screenshots or something that i can really understand